# UWP - Don't fire Click event when pressing space (like in Movies & TV app)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am working on custom media player and trying to reproduce same behavior as in Movies & TV app (Windows 10 CU).

<kbd>Space</kbd> is used to Play & Pause video no matter what. <kbd>Space</kbd> **is not** used to click buttons when they are focused (but <kbd>Enter</kbd> is). This behavior breaks some rules about keyboard [accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/accessibility/keyboard-accessibility#keyboard-alternatives-to-pointer-actions-and-events-for-specific-control-elements), but I think it is OK. <kbd>Space</kbd> for Play & Pause is something that user expect.

Question is: How they did it?

I found some half-solutions:

**Solution 1**  `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown` and `if` in `Click Event Handler`

*Page.xaml.cs:*

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
  Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindowOnKeyDown;
  //...
 }

 bool isItSpace;

 private void CoreWindowOnKeyDown(CoreWindow sender, KeyEventArgs args)
 {  
    if (args.VirtualKey ==  VirtualKey.Space)
    isItSpace = true;
 }


 private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (isItSpace)
     {
       isItSpace = false;
       return;
     }
    //...
 }
```

*Page.xaml:*

```
<Button  Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"  >Button Text</Button>
```

*Why not:*

- Need to add `if` in every Click Handler
- There is button click animation...

**Solution 2** Disable focused Button in `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown` and enable it in `KeyUp`

Something like:

```
    if (FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() is Button)
    {
        var bu = (Button)FocusManager.GetFocusedElement();
        bu.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

*Why not*

- It change focus from disabled button. Need to change it back after enable. Focus is jumping..
- Disable and enable animation appear
- it is too hackie

**Solution 3** `button.ClickMode = ClickMode.Hover`

When `ClickMode` is set to `Hover` it is not possible to Click it with keyboard. When I change it in `KeyDown` handler of Window (like solution 2) it still bubble to Click event for the first time. Solution could be set all buttons to `Hover`, but in that case <kbd>Enter</kbd> will not cause the Click and I need to change all buttons...

Are there any better solutions on your mind?

Comment: In my mind, you can use a property to indicate the play/pause state. And in XAML, you can bind the Button to this property. Then in KeyDown event, you can just change this property and the Button should be able to change automatically.

Comment: @Scavenger I don't have problem with Play & Pause on Space press. But Space press causes more actions by default - that's the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue comes down to, when you click on a button from the media command bar, it automatically gets *focused*, and keybaord keys like <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> will automatically trigger the action of the button.

So to solve the issue, you just need to find a way to remove the auto-focus from them.

Prior to Windows 10 build *14393*, you can try manually setting the focus to some other element after the click, but this feels like a hack to me.

In *14393*, they introduced a new property called `AllowFocusOnInteraction` which can help you in this particular case. Basically, what this does is to **not** auto-focus a control after the user interacts with it, so the focus will remain on the currently focused element.

To apply this, you will need to obtain the default style of the [MediaTransportControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt414180.aspx) control, where you can have access to all the media command bar buttons.

Then you just attach `AllowFocusOnInteraction="False"` to all the `AppBarButton`s (don't forget buttons inside `Flyout`s such as `AudioMuteButton`!) except the `PlayPauseButton`.

I would even go one step further to manually set the focus on the `PlayPauseButton` when the page is initially loaded. So after that whenever the <kbd>Space</kbd> key is hit, you will see a nice *pressed* visual on this button to indicate the play/pause action has been invoked.

Please also note doing this will **not** affect keybaord navigation. If the user wants, he can still use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to navigate between buttons. So general user accessibility is not affected.

---

### Update

I personally would like any focused button to react on <kbd>Space</kbd> key press, but if you want the absolute same visual behavior as in the offical *Films & TV* app, that's possible too.

Rather than writting a lot of code-behind, let's create an `ExtendedAppBarButton` that encapsulates all the logic.

The idea is very similar with your *Solution 2*, we will use

```
AddHandler(KeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(OnKeyDown), true);
AddHandler(KeyUpEvent, new KeyEventHandler(OnKeyUp), true);
```

to toggle `IsEnabled` whenever the <kbd>Space</kbd> key is pressed. Also, we will have a special `IsPlayPauseButton` dependency property that subscribes to the `KeyDown` event of the `Window` to manually invoke the button click, whenever it's set to `True`.

Inside the default style of our `ExtendedAppBarButton`, we need to make sure we have the following set properly -

```
<Setter Property="Width" Value="{ThemeResource MTCMediaButtonWidth}" />
<Setter Property="Height" Value="{ThemeResource MTCMediaButtonHeight}" />
<Setter Property="AllowFocusOnInteraction" Value="False" />
<Setter Property="AllowFocusWhenDisabled" Value="True" />
<Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False" />
```

Note the `UseSystemFocusVisuals` is set to `False` 'cause we are creating our own focus visual to avoid the system one flashing issue that you have already noticed.

```
<Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisual"
           Opacity="0"
           StrokeThickness="2"
           Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
```

Also, we will remove the `Storybaord` inside the `Disabled` state as we don't want any animation to happen between the `IsEnabled` property changes.

Finally, you will need to obtain the default style of `MediaTransportControls` and replace all the `AppBarButton`s with the one we just created.

There's a lot of stuff going on here, but once you have everything setup, you don't need to worry about handling all these on your media pages ever.

I have created a simple demo project [here](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/ExtendedAppBarButtonOnMediaCommandBar) in case anything is unclear. Feel free to check it out.

Comment: This moved me forward little bit, but it is not the desired solution... In Movie&TV - Focusing any button with Tab and hitting Space does not cause any action except for Play&Pause. Space is somehow disabled for interactions (but Enter is not).

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer. I think it now does exactly what you want.

Comment: @JustinXL This is a great solution with demo app but I have a question that will this solution affect other platforms like xbox? bcz that tab focused elements with space/enter works well for accesbility on xbox so with this solution you gave it still works with Enter button, so will it work as expected on xbox? i.e : ok button on xbox to click any button on command bar?( or whatever button they have on xbox controller for it )

Comment: @JustinXL and also I was wondering if we can add another feature to it. i.e : when the seekbar is focused we can seek it with arrow keys, with up/down or right/left. Can we change behaviour so that only right/left keys can seek and up/down do nothing? Because I wanted to assign the up/down keys for volume. And also if the volume flyout bar is focused, only updown keys change that bar and right/left doesnt do anything on it.