# uwp space bar to pause media, triggers last used button

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, mediaelement, onkeydown

I have set Space bar button to **Pause/play** my media element in my app, but for example If I use a command with pointer, forexample fullscreen, or mute or any other functionality, apart from pause play, and then when I press **space button** it pauses/plays media as it is supposed to but it also triggers last command which I used with pointer or touch ( e.g : full screen toggle button). I know why this happens, is because those buttons have focus and then when I press space bar they are triggered as well.
My question is how can I prevent this on this specific page? I don't want the space bar or any other key to do anything else on that page, apart from the functions I have assigned through **keydown and keyup** events.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Also have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748723/uwp-dont-fire-click-event-when-pressing-space-like-in-movies-tv-app/44856044#44856044).

Comment: Actually, I just updated that answer with a working demo. Feel free to check it out also. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you detect a spacebar press, just set the focus to the page or some other control:

```
this.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

Comment: yes I tried that but it doesn't work I guess the default function of key down executes before it.

Comment: then instead do it after each action which affect your focus on this page, say after full screen toggle - set focus to page.