# Canceling the SpaceBar Click/Tap on uwp controls throughout the app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, keyboard-shortcuts, media-player

When a UI element ( control ) is focused in a uwp app it can be triggered with <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> or the <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys, this is not limited to Desktop but also helps in Xbox so user can navigate through the controls and press on any focused control to active its `Command`.

**Use case**

But in My use case I want only <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to trigger that behaviour and <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> should not do anything at all no matter which control is pressed on the screen.

The reason to this requirement is that I am building a `MediaPlayer` application and no matter which control or button is focused within the app when I press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> I want to simply link it to the **Play/Pause** Behaviour of my media element.

**Not a Duplicate**

This question is not a duplicate of : [UWP - Don't fire Click event when pressing space (like in Movies & TV app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748723/uwp-dont-fire-click-event-when-pressing-space-like-in-movies-tv-app)

Because in the question linked above, the answer was only relevant if any of the `AppBarButtons` were focused so they will not do anything on pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> but only will be invoked with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. But in my use case I want to apply the same behavior even outside the `MediaPlayerElement` control. I have a `NavigationView` and `MediaPlayerElement` resides in one of the pages, so I want this behavior to work even when a `NavigationViewItem` is focused or any other control which can be focused and invoked should only be invoked with **Enter** and not <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Is there a app level solution where I can apply this behaviour at the very root control and it descends to all of its children i.e : whole app?

**What I have tried**

I have tried with the already answered question (linked above) and that works fine for its limited scenario. And I have also tried setting `AllowFocusOnInteraction=false` to every app bar button and also other extra controls I have in the style of my `CustomMediaTransportControls`. But this is also limited to `MediaPlayerElement` only and also it prevents tab navigation which is not good for accessibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by handling the `PreviewKeyDown` event higher in the visual tree hierarchy, for example in the `Page`.

Subscribe to the event in the `Page` constructor:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.PreviewKeyDown += MainPage_PreviewKeyDown;            
}
```

Or in XAML:

```
<Page ... PreviewKeyDown="MainPage_PreviewKeyDown">
```

And in the event handler set the `KeyRoutedEventArgs` to handled when the <kbd>Space</kbd> key was pressed:

```
private void MainPage_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Space)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This way the key down event will never reach any control below in the hierarchy because the `PreviewKeyDown` event propagates the tree before the event takes place.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways could approach, You could listen the current [`Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.window.content#Windows_UI_Xaml_Window_Content) [`PreviewKeyDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.previewkeydown) event to detect <kbd>Space</kbd> press.

```
public Scenario1()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.Content.PreviewKeyDown += Content_PreviewKeyDown;  
}

private void Content_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = e.Key == VirtualKey.Space ? true : false;
}
```

You could also GLOBAL HOTKEY for your uwp app that could be used when your app's window not in foreground. For more derail you could check this [blog](https://stefanwick.com/2018/05/15/global-hotkey-registration-in-uwp/) .